# Premake5 xcode4 Action: bad argument #1 to 'pairs'

Tags: premake

I'm newer to Premake, but I have used it successfully in Visual Studio projects on Windows. Now, I have a premake5 script that works fine for Visual Studio and Makefile projects, but xcode and codelite projects fail:

```
$ premake5 --verbose xcode4
Building configurations...
Running action 'xcode4'...
Error: [string "xcode/xcode_common.lua"]:201: bad argument #1 to 'pairs'
    (table expected, got nil)
```

XCode and CodeLite support is listed as mostly working; can anyone tell me if there's some specific issue I'm bumping into in the premake listings below? The solution is really quite simple.

My main Premake solution file:
src/premake5.lua

```
solution "LogicCore"

    -- set the major and minor build numbers
    VERSION_MAJOR = 1
    VERSION_MINOR = 0

    major = "VERSION_MAJOR=" .. VERSION_MAJOR; 
    minor = "VERSION_MINOR=" .. VERSION_MINOR; 

    defines { major, minor }

    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

    configuration { "Debug" }
        targetdir "../bin/debug"

    configuration { "Release" }
        targetdir "../bin/release"

    if _ACTION == "clean" then
        os.rmdir("../bin")
    end

    -- PROJECT: Generic include and utility functions.
    include "lc"
```

My Premake sub-project file:
src/lc/premake5.lua

```
project "lc"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C"
    location "./"
    files { "**.h", "**.c" }

    configuration {"Debug"}
        targetsuffix "_d";
        defines { "DEBUG" };
        flags { "Symbols" };

    configuration {"Release"}
        defines { "NDEBUG" };
        flags { "Optimize" };
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I saw that you also [opened an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues/330). I will take a look as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: There is also Blizzard https://github.com/Blizzard/premake-core premake fork, which seems to support Xcode6, try it